# Puzzling problem with Arduino on USB at boot

Tags: python, usb, arduino

I have an Arduino Uno (R3) monitoring a magnetometer connected via USB to a PI (B) running latest Raspian. My Pi Python program scans the USB every second reading an integer value via 
`ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 57600)`.

This works fine when run from an active terminal. However I want to run the Python program starting at boot. Now the Python program fails to read the USB state.

I have tried starting the program via both `rc.local` and `crontab`. In either case the Python script is happy, reading/writing its data files, but fails when it tries to access USB. I have inserted a wait of up to 2 min assuming that USB may take time to initialize.

I wonder whether the USB is disabled until active login? Am I simply being dim here? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it. The problem was that I was not flushing the buffer first

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 57600)
ser.flushInput()
```

Comment: Perhaps also consider setting [timeout](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial) when you open the device